# Show month and day from array/hash

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to show the closest date. I have the following code:

```
def closest_birthdate(birthdates)
  sorted_dates = birthdates.sort_by do |_, value|
    (DateTime.parse(value) - DateTime.now).abs
  end
  name, birthday = sorted_dates.first
  "#{name} has his birthday on #{birthday} "
end

hash = {
  'William' =>  '2017-09-05',
  'Henk' =>     '2017-10-12',
  'Richard' =>  '2017-10-10',
}
closest_birthdate(hash)
```

The output is:

```
"William has his birthday on 2017-10-5"
```

How can I display only the month and day like the following?

```
"William has his birthday on 10-5"
```

I tried to delete the years in the hash, but I think the code doesn't recognize dates anymore if I do that.

Comment: Why do you store the dates as strings instead of `Date` instances?

Comment: BTW, unless you are dealing with historic dates, you should use `Time` instead of `DateTime` (or just `Date` if you don't need the time part). See [When should you use `DateTime` and when should you use `Time`?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F)

Comment: Another "BTW" – birthdates are usually stored using the year a person was born in rather than the current year. This makes it a little trickier to find the closest date, but it's much more useful (age). Also note that `closest_birthdate` will eventually return dates in the past if they are closest. You are probably interested in the next (i.e. future) birthdate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
require 'date'

"#{name} has his birthday on #{Date.parse(birthday).strftime('%m-%d')}"
```

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to go with it. They'll show you lots of format options if you want to get crazy.

Comment: @Doeple that's because when creating your hash you've made the date a string. #strftime works on a Time/Date object. ursus' new answer parses it back to a Date.

Comment: It's helpful to readers new to Ruby (here that includes the asker) to show needed `require`s (`require 'date'`).  Also, a reminder that [Date::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) is fraught with peril: `Date.parse("09 cat lives") #=> #<Date: 2017-10-09 ((2458036j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.  [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) would be safer: `Date.strptime('2017-07-23', '%Y-%m-%d') #=> #<Date: 2017-07-23 ((2457958j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Comment: You're right @CarySwoveland :) Would you like to complete my answer?

Comment: I have this old-school reluctance to edit other people's work. It may not be rational, but I can't help it.

Comment: Don't worry @CarySwoveland :)